# Select a row in Windowed select based on set time difference in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, group-by

Using this table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
[session] [bigint] NULL,
[an] [varchar](10) NULL,
[skformat] [int] NULL,
[skmean] [int] NULL,
[mediatype] [varchar](10) NULL,
[rectime] [datetime] NULL,
[prod] [varchar](10) NULL
)

GO

INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([session], [an], [skformat], [skmean], [mediatype], 
[rectime], [prod]) VALUES (123, N'123abc', 2, 3, N'pdf', CAST(N'2017-09-27 
11:51:08.210' AS DateTime), N'abc')
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([session], [an], [skformat], [skmean], [mediatype], 
[rectime], [prod]) VALUES (123, N'123abc', 2, 3, N'pdf', CAST(N'2017-09-27 
11:56:08.210' AS DateTime), N'def')
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([session], [an], [skformat], [skmean], [mediatype], 
[rectime], [prod]) VALUES (123, N'456hlm', 4, 5, N'hlm', CAST(N'2017-09-27 
11:51:09.210' AS DateTime), N'ghi')
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([session], [an], [skformat], [skmean], [mediatype], 
[rectime], [prod]) VALUES (123, N'456hlm', 4, 5, N'hlm', CAST(N'2017-09-27 
11:51:10.210' AS DateTime), N'xyz')
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([session], [an], [skformat], [skmean], [mediatype], 
[rectime], [prod]) VALUES (123, N'1a2b3c', 2, 2, N'pdf', CAST(N'2017-09-27 
11:51:08.210' AS DateTime), N'fbi')
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([session], [an], [skformat], [skmean], [mediatype], 
[rectime], [prod]) VALUES (555, N'555xyz', 1, 1, N'pdf', CAST(N'2017-09-27 
11:54:44.050' AS DateTime), N'abc')
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([session], [an], [skformat], [skmean], [mediatype], 
[rectime], [prod]) VALUES (555, N'555xyz', 1, 1, N'pdf', CAST(N'2017-09-27 
11:54:40.050' AS DateTime), N'def')
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([session], [an], [skformat], [skmean], [mediatype], 
[rectime], [prod]) VALUES (555, N'5x5y5z', 4, 6, N'hlm', CAST(N'2017-09-27 
11:54:45.050' AS DateTime), N'ghi')
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([session], [an], [skformat], [skmean], [mediatype], 
[rectime], [prod]) VALUES (555, N'5x5y5z', 4, 6, N'hlm', CAST(N'2017-09-27 
11:54:45.050' AS DateTime), N'xyz')
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([session], [an], [skformat], [skmean], [mediatype], 
[rectime], [prod]) VALUES (555, N'555xxx', 1, 2, N'pdf', CAST(N'2017-09-27 
11:54:44.050' AS DateTime), N'fbi')
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([session], [an], [skformat], [skmean], [mediatype], 
[rectime], [prod]) VALUES (555, N'555xyz', 1, 1, N'pdf', CAST(N'2017-09-27 
11:54:39.050' AS DateTime), NULL)
```

I created this windowed query:

```
select session,an,skformat,skmean,mediatype,rectime,
row_number() over 
 (partition by session,an,skformat,skmean,mediatype
 order by rectime asc) as row
 from MyTable
 group by session,an,skformat,skmean,mediatype,rectime
 order by session, an
```

Good so far...

But what I'd like to do is just select the first row of each grouping (when there is more than one row) IF the time difference (rectime field) is less than 10 seconds when mediatype=pdf and is less than 30 seconds when mediatype=hlm

Stuck here. Advice appreciated.

This this the result I'm looking for:

```
session an  skformat    skmean  mediatype   rectime row

123 123abc  2   3   pdf 11:51:08 AM 1

123 123abc  2   3   pdf 11:56:08 AM 2

123 1a2b3c  2   2   pdf 11:51:08 AM 1

123 456hlm  4   5   hlm 11:51:09 AM 1

555 555xxx  1   2   pdf 11:54:44 AM 1

555 555xyz  1   1   pdf 11:54:39 AM 1

555 5x5y5z  4   6   hlm 11:54:45 AM 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Schema: check! Sample data: check! Existing query: check! Expected results: missing. Please edit your question to include the results you seek.

Comment: Sorry, added result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query.

```
;WITH T AS (
    SELECT *,
        row_number() over ( order by rectime desc ) as row
    FROM MyTable
 )
 SELECT session, an,  skformat,    skmean,  mediatype,   rectime FROM T T1
 WHERE 
 NOT EXISTS (SELECT * , DATEDIFF(SECOND, T2.rectime ,T1.rectime ) dff FROM T T2 WHERE 
        T2.row > T1.row 
        AND T2.session = T1.session
        AND T2.an = T1.an
        AND T2.skformat = T1.skformat
        AND T2.skmean = T1.skmean
        AND T2.mediatype = T1.mediatype
        AND ( DATEDIFF(SECOND, T2.rectime ,T1.rectime ) < CASE mediatype WHEN 'pdf ' THEN 10 ELSE 30 END)
        ) 
ORDER BY session, an, rectime
```

Result

```
session              an         skformat    skmean      mediatype  rectime
-------------------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ---------- -----------------------
123                  123abc     2           3           pdf        2017-09-27 11:51:08.210
123                  123abc     2           3           pdf        2017-09-27 11:56:08.210
123                  1a2b3c     2           2           pdf        2017-09-27 11:51:08.210
123                  456hlm     4           5           hlm        2017-09-27 11:51:09.210
555                  555xxx     1           2           pdf        2017-09-27 11:54:44.050
555                  555xyz     1           1           pdf        2017-09-27 11:54:39.050
555                  5x5y5z     4           6           hlm        2017-09-27 11:54:45.050
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: One question, any idea how this will perform over millions of rows?

Comment: hard to say anything before try, it some depends on server performance and indexes on the table, but it would take couples of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT session 
                ,an 
                ,skformat 
                ,skmean 
                ,mediatype 
                ,rectime 
                ,Row_number() 
                   OVER ( 
                     partition BY session, an, skformat, skmean, mediatype 
                     ORDER BY rectime ASC) AS row 
                ,Lead(rectime, 1, rectime) 
                   OVER ( 
                     partition BY session, an, skformat, skmean, mediatype 
                     ORDER BY rectime ASC) rectime_lead 
         FROM   mytable 
         GROUP  BY session 
                   ,an 
                   ,skformat 
                   ,skmean 
                   ,mediatype 
                   ,rectime) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  row = 1 
       AND ( ( mediatype = 'pdf' 
               AND Datediff(second, rectime, rectime_lead) < 10 ) 
              OR ( mediatype = 'hlm' 
                   AND Datediff(second, rectime, rectime_lead) < 30 ) )
```

Comment: Thanks, but that only returns 2 rows. See my edited question for the result I want.

Comment: I edited the result. Now I think it is ok. About your example, the line (123 123abc  2   3   pdf 11:51:08 AM 1) has 30 seconds of difference, and the type is PDF. The line (123 123abc  2   3   pdf 11:56:08 AM 2) is not the first row of the group. If I not correct, why those lines are in the result.

Comment: Mauricio, I appreciate you help, thank you! But the result you provided is still not correct. In the example I provided there is no 30 second data. The result I provide above is the result I'm looking for. I will work with what you have given me, thanks alot!